# How to initialize an edittext with a empty string if i am using a two way databinding and a double as attribute?

Tags: android, android-databinding

I am using the binding in edittext like this

```
android:text='@={autuacao.equipamento.limite  + ""}'
```

limite is a primitive  double.

But when the activity starts, the edittext is initialized as 0.0, and i need it to be empty, how can i do this?

Answer (score 1):

Tynn The answer was almost there but the parameters should be like below, and i didn't need the inverse binder.

```
@BindingAdapter("android:text")
public static void setText(EditText editText, String value) {

    if (value == null) {
        return;
    }
    if (value.equals("0.0")) {
        editText.setText("");
    } else {
        editText.setText(value);
    }
}
```

Comment: You're amazing!!! I provided a Kotlin version based on your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could get around it by defining your own binding adapter:

```
@BindingAdapter("android:text")
public static void setDoubleToText(TextView view, double value) {
    String text = "";
    if (value != 0) {
        text = String.valueOf(value);
    }
    view.setText(text);
}
```

Additionally you might also need to define the inverse behavior:

```
@InverseBindingAdapter(attribute = "android:text")
public static double getDoubleFromText(TextView view) {
    try {
        return Double.parseDouble(view.getText().toString());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return 0.0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Kotlin Version:**

```
object DataBindingUtil {
    @BindingAdapter("android:text")
    @JvmStatic
    fun setExtraBehaviorForEditText(editText: EditText, text: String?) {
        if (text == "0" || text == "0.0") editText.setText("") else editText.setText(text)
    }
}
```